# How to call the right number of arguments in a function?

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler

I am trying to convert MATLAB code to C/C++. My code generates successfully and the Mex is built, but fails while running the test file with MEX. Below is the function and the error message I am receiving.

```
   function[A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, F6] = fcn(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
```

Caused by:
Function 'Numbers' called with wrong number of arguments: expected 9, received 0.

Comment: And what is the test file you are running that generates the error? Note we have no way of helping you with the little information you have given. Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.